# Python, flask, methods variable not found. Does the variable no longer exist?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to send a form to a python server using flask as the framework, however the methods variable keeps giving me an error that no such variable exists. I have tried googling it but haven't found anything online.

```
from flask import Flask, request 
@app.route('/form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
    # allow for both POST AND GET
    if request.method == 'POST':
        language = request.form.get('language')
        framework = request.form.get('framework')
        return '''
                          <h1>The language value is: {}</h1>
                          <h1>The framework value is: {}</h1>'''.format(language, framework)
    # otherwise handle the get request
    return '''
              <form method="POST">
                  <div><label>Language: <input type="text" name="language"></label></div>
                  <div><label>Framework: <input type="text" name="framework"></label></div>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
              </form>'
              '''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask, request 
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
    # allow for both POST AND GET
    if request.method == 'POST':
        language = request.form.get('language')
        framework = request.form.get('framework')
        return '''
                          <h1>The language value is: {}</h1>
                          <h1>The framework value is: {}</h1>'''.format(language, framework)
    # otherwise handle the get request
    return '''
              <form method="POST">
                  <div><label>Language: <input type="text" name="language"></label></div>
                  <div><label>Framework: <input type="text" name="framework"></label></div>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
              </form>'
              '''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

by adding these two code blocks in the code as shown in the above code, the app is working perfectly fine.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Hmm okay thanks, maybe it has something more to do with my own local library for flask

Comment: Yes, you can try reinstalling python or try running the code in a virtual environment